# Как в html строке удалить div при помощи javascript

Tags: javascript, php, html, html5

Я хотел удалить div через javascript, php, да хоть что угодно. То есть мне нужно удалить всё, что содержится в `<div>` и сам div, хотя если кто-то знает, как удалить всё, что содержится в `<div>`, не удаляя его, то это тоже подойдёт, но лучше всего удалить ещё и сам div.

Вот код:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
 <html>
  <head>
   <title>Сайт</title>
  <body>
   <div id="nenadoudalit">тут что-то есть</div>
   <div id="nadoudalit">тут что-то есть</div> <!--Надо удалить этот div с id nadoudalit-->
   <div id="nenadoudalit2">тут что-то есть</div>
  </body>
```

Возможно ли это? Я искал решение этой проблемы, но так и не нашёл чего-то, что могло бы мне помочь.

Хотя, возможно решение будет примерно таким (javascript):

```
getElementById(nadoudalit);
nadoudalit.slice(0, 0)
```

Или я ошибаюсь... Вообще, я ни разу не пользовался getElementById, поэтому и не знаю, как им пользоваться.

Comment: https://codepen.io/topicstarter/pen/mdJMOMM вот так наверно если не удаляя сам блок

Answer (score 1, accepted):

так надо было проверить для начала :)
а еще лучше документацию почитать какую-нибудь.

Метод slice() возвращает новый массив, содержащий копию части исходного массива.

вот так надо:

```
document.getElementById("nadoudalit").remove();
```

Answer (score 1):

так

```js
document.getElementById("nadoudalit").remove();
```

```html
<div id="main">
    <div id="nenadoudalit">тут что-то есть</div>
    <div id="nadoudalit">тут что-то есть</div> <!--Надо удалить этот div с id 
 nadoudalit-->
    <div id="nenadoudalit2">тут что-то есть</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Просто придайте через id ненужному диву класс и скройте через css. display: none; 
Так он у вас не будет нигде отображаться и если что всегда можно вернуть обратно.

Comment: Я так и хотел сделать, но способ с document.getElementById("id").remove(); лучше. Всё равно спасибо вам

Answer (score 1):

```
const el=document.getElementById('nadoudalit');
el.parentNode.removeChild(el);
```